# For cyclus python3 with if statement

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

What is wrong with this cycle, please that the output is

```
0
One
1
One
2
One
3
One
4
One
5
One


for i in range(6):
    print(i)
    if i == 0 or 2 or 4:
        print('One')
    else:
        print('Two')
```

I would expect alternate printing of One and Two. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the below changes in your `if` statement:

```
for i in range(6):
    print(i)
    if i == 0 or i == 2 or i == 4:
        print('One')
    else:
        print('Two')
```

Your `if i == 0 or 2 or 4:` is equivalent to `if (i == 0) or 2 or 4:` and hence will compute as always `true`.